# Cross-Origin Request Blocked on Axios POST request (VueJS)

Tags: forms, api, vue.js, post, vuejs2

I am trying to send a POST request upon form submit and keep running into CORS issues. I get the following errors:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/api/lists/contacts.
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

and

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/api/lists/contacts.
(Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

This is my code:

```js
<template>
   <form @submit.prevent="subscribeEmail" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
     <input type="email" v-model="email" name="user_email">
     <button type="submit" name="button">Subscribe</button>
   </form>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  methods: {
    subscribeEmail() {
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `https://example.com/api/lists/${id}/contacts`,
            data: {
                "api_key": apiKey,
                "email_address":  this.email,
            },
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Furthermore, this is the network description of my request. For some reason the method is OPTION...
[image]

I can't figure out what the problem is. I tried a bunch of things. I would really appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks a ton in advance.

Note: this issue is happening both on localhost and on the production version (Netlify).

Comment: The CORS headers must be set on the server that hosts the API, not from you sending it. Otherwise any client can just send a header that forcibly downgrade CORS policy on the remote server.

Comment: The `OPTIONS` request is the CORS preflight, see https://cors-errors.info/faq#a313. You need to enable CORS on the server. Adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the client won't help.

Comment: Terry, skirtle,

When you are referring to the server, do you mean the server where I host my code (Netlify) or the server that I send the request to (example.com)? If the latter, then I am not sure what to do since it is a third-party service. Will have to contact them, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the email marketing service I was using specifically does not allow for client-side API calls for security reasons.

If you are having a similar issue, try contacting the service that provides the API. They might be able to help.

To bypass this, one method you could use is to direct the request through a proxy. Most popular solution is to use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/. You basically append this urls to your request like so:

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com/api/action`,
    data: {
       "api_key": apiKey,
       "email_address":  this.email,
    },
    headers: {
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
       'Content-type': 'application/json',
    }
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try to launch your browser without CORS:

Linux Terminal (Chrome Browser): `google-chrome --user-data-dir="/var/tmp/Chrome" --disable-web-security`

Comment: Thank you, this is the only thing that worked for me...